# I want a field to copy (duplicate) the data from another field

Tags: cognito-forms

I am building a Booking Form for my tours. So for the Lead Passenger I created a field named `TRIP CODE`. I want that code to be duplicated in the additional passenger field without having to type it again.

So I created the same field in the additional passenger section and wrote the formula `=TripCode` in this new text field. But it is not working.

I just realized that when working in this `ADDITIONAL PASSERGERS` section (which is a repeating section) fields formulas work with the fields created only in this section but not in the ones created outside this section.

Comment: Yes, this is a current limitation for calculations, that they are limited to fields within the current section or sub-sections.  We are planning to address this in our next release.

Answer (score 1):

You can enter calculations for the Default Value of a field in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) to be the value of another field.  This will copy the data from the other field when it changes, but still allow the user to make changes.

For example, if your first field is named Field 1, then the Default Value of Field 2 should be `=Field1`.

Comment: It is not working! It should be simple...

Comment: Yes, calculations can be quite simple, but when you are dealing with a hierarchical form with sections and repeating sections is will become a bit more complex.